# signalR performance counters + azure VM+ full IIS + windows server 2012

Tags: azure, redis, virtual-machine, iis-7.5

Really stuck on this problem.
I have a signalr test harness app on a azure VM ful iis running on redis backplane using Linux. 
The app works as expected locally. I can connect to my Linux node running redis server. And performance counters show messages received per second.

But when I load the app on azure VM, the app still connects to redis backplane but the performance counters for messages recevied or published stay at zero. 
I logged into Linux node and checked redis server was receiving messages but the performance counters showed zero on azure VM...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean your SignalR running on Azure Windows VM, and your redis running on on-prem Linux?

Comment: yes exactly. Not just this, I have a sql server running on azure vm (IAAS) and signalr on another windows vm, testing on local IIS express i can  see the counters update. but I dont know why they wont update on full iis..

Comment: Maybe we should check NSG and firewall settings. can VMs communicate with each other?

Comment: yes, they can, i think the problem lies in having permissions to read performance counters.

Comment: Select which counter from computer? or can you show the screenshot about your Azure VM performance monitor?

Comment: all the signalR performance counters. the only counters that seem to update are connections connected and connections disconnected :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149190/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-syler).

Comment: Let us discusses in the chat room.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, it seems that we can't add performance counters to collect performance data.

Maybe we can use **OMS/Log Analytics**, that can pull in custom performance counters and display them.

About use OMS to collect custom performance data, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-data-sources-performance-counters).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hey jason, i appreciate your help. The problem i found a fix for, was because I had to create more client connections and now i can see perf mon reporting data.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue has been resolved. Could you please post your detailed solution to this issue as an answer so that other community members will be benefited.